# wpf Problems with StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have a TextBlock with MultiBinding in the Text property, and StringFormat to concatenate the two results with some additions.

```
<TextBlock.Text>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}" >
      <Binding Path="Version" />
       <Binding Path="OldVersion" StringFormat="{}'({0})'" TargetNullValue=""/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

The first StringFormat works as expected, but the second isn't applied: it returns the value without parentheses. I don't want the parentheses in the first StringFormat, because sometimes the second value is Nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: couldn't you put the parenthesis in the first StringFormat? `<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})" >`

Comment: I can not put it that the first, because the second parameter is sometimes nothing, And I want to use the TargetNullValue, As I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner `StringFormat` will be ignored when you use `MultiBinding` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)).

> When you use a MultiBinding, the StringFormat property applies only
>   when it is set on the MultiBinding. The value of StringFormat that is
>   set on any child Binding objects is ignored. The number of parameters
>   in a composite string format cannot exceed the number of child Binding
>   objects in the MultiBinding.

Instead of `MultiBinding` you can use following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OldVersion, StringFormat=({0}), TargetNullValue=''}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Or you can create wrapper property to `OldVersion` property:

```
public string OldVersionEx
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(OldVersion))
            return null;
        else
            return "(" + OldVersion + ")";
    }
}
```

And binding in this case is following:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}" >
            <Binding Path="Version" />
            <Binding Path="OldVersionEx"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's Very hekpfull